# PHP 7 & Doctrine 2.4.3 : Changing column charset from utf8 to utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, doctrine-orm, utf8mb4

I'm working on a project using Doctrine 2.4.3 with a MySQL 5.7.21 database with `utf8` as default charset.

Recently, I've been looking to implement emoji support. To overcome MySQL's limitation of 3 bytes for `utf8`, I need to change the columns that can receive emojis to the `utf8mb4` charset (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

However, I have not found a way to reflect this in my entities (using annotations).

My database connection config is the following :

```
$data = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => $dbhost,
    'port' => $dbport,
    'dbname' => $dbname,
    'user' => $dbuser,
    'password' => $dbpw,
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4'
);
```

I tried adding annotations to the table :

`/* @Entity(repositoryClass="path\to\DAO") @Table(name="post", indexes={@Index(name="uid", columns={"uid"})}, options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
class Post extends BaseEntity
{
    ...
}`

In the same fashion, tried adding annotations to the column (in the same table) itself :

`/* @Column(type="text", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"}) */
protected $text;`

None of the above worked. I expected an `ALTER TABLE` query when executing `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` but Doctrine sees no change, and I still can't insert 4 bytes emojis.

If I update the column's charset myself directly in MySQL, emojis do get supported, but when I do run `orm:schema-tool:update`, Doctrine sees a difference between my entity and the schema, but seems to not know what to make of it since the output I get is the following :
`ALTER TABLE post CHANGE text text LONGTEXT  NOT NULL ;`

I also tried to add `SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as `driverOptions` in my database connection config array, alas to no result either.

Unfortunately, I could not find anything regarding this matter in Doctrine's documentation.

If any of you has any clue regarding this matter, feel free to hit me up! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have legacy requirements and cannot update Doctrine's lib as of right now, I had to find a workaround.

What I did was manually convert my tables to `utf8mb4` with SQL queries, which is not overwritten by Doctrine back to `utf8` when executing `orm:schema-tool:update --force` after the charset conversion.

For the record, I generated the update statements with the following script :

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;')
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_schema LIKE {your_schema};
```

^ Do not execute this blindly - check beforehand if existing data will fit while `utf8mb4` encoded. For more details check the very good article from Mathias Bynens on the matter : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#column-index-length

I also changed the database's charset settings.

```
ALTER DATABASE {database_name} CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I did keep the `'charset' => 'utf8mb4'` in the Doctrine's database connection settings array for correct transmission of the data.

For new entities (tables), annotating them with correct settings in table options does create them with the right charset and collation :

```
@Entity @Table(name="table", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the whole table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
```

For more troubleshooting:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do know how to change the charset on the table/columns, my problem here is reflecting that change in my Doctrine entities. When running Doctrine's schema updating tool, it sees there's a difference (since the Entity is not annotated as 'utf8mb4' but the actual table in the database is) but can't provide the correct request to update the schema accordingly. Thanks anyway.